# Не грузится карта на некоторых мобильных устройствах Android

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-jsapi

Возникла проблема с показом карты на некоторых мобильных устройствах. Проблема возникает из-за кастомных иконок для маркеров и кластеров, то есть если сделать иконки стандартными какой нибудь `islands#redIcon` то карта загружается. Проверил на iphone проблема не возникает, только на некоторых устройствах Android, не могли бы Вы подсказать в чем может быть проблема. Ниже прикладываю листинг кода:

```
var objectIconMin =[
        {
            iconContentSize: [130, 130],
            iconLayout: "default#imageWithContent",
            iconImageHref: '/bitrix/components/bstd/get.map.cords/templates/.default/image/min.svg',
            //iconImageOffset: [-70, -150],iconImageSize: [130, 145],
            iconImageOffset: [-35, -75],
            iconImageSize: [65, 72.5],
            iconShadow: false,
            balloonPanelMaxMapArea: 0
        }
    ];
var clusterIcons = [
        {
            href: '/bitrix/components/bstd/get.map.cords/templates/.default/image/max.svg',
            //size: [150, 150],offset: [-70, -150]
            size: [100, 100],
            offset: [-50, -100]
        }
    ];
objectManager.objects.options.set('preset',objectIconMin);


objectManager.clusters.options.set({clusterIcons});
```

Comment: Опишите, пожалуйста, на каких версиях Android и в каких браузерах возникает проблема. Какой webView используется? Есть ли ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Не загружается вся карта или только кастомные иконки?

Comment: обнаружил на Kitkat4.4(Asus Zenfone 5) и на Flyme 5.1.4.1(MEIZU M3).
webView используется стандартный
Ошибок в консоли нет.

Comment: objectManager.objects.options.set('preset',objectIconMin);
objectManager.clusters.options.set({clusterIcons}
Если установлены то не загружаеться карта вообще, просто белый экран, если закоментить то карта грузиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за ваше внимание, проблема была решена.
После того как воспользовался минификатором в ECMAScript 2018 (via Babili), карта начала работать на данных устройствах, в чем именно была проблемма мне так и не удалось выяснить